# Post data into JSON Array with Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to build a chat system but I can't insert
 a users message into my JSON array here is my code:
JSON:

```
{
    "user": ["theredcrafteryt", "jacksucksatlife", "imacow"],
    "message": ["hey", "hi", "hello"]
}
```

I am trying to insert the user's username
and the message into the array.

Here is what I'm trying to get:

```
{
    "user": ["theredcrafteryt", "jacksucksatlife", "imacow", "user's name"],
    "message": ["hey", "hi", "hello", "user's message"]
}
```

Comment: Post the expected output, please.

Comment: The code you currently have which produces the unexpected output might be helpful as well.

Comment: Please post your code. It is impossible to track the bug without looking at the code.